# Sharepoint 2013: simple api call not working

Tags: rest, api

```
[site name]_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘ListName’)/items
```

So why does this not work? All the examples I see indicate that it should work.

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>
-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException
</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
The expression "web/lists/GetByTitle(‘ListName’)/items" is not valid.
</m:message>
</m:error>
```

---

(20161101) More info:

I’m working through this example: [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2014/08/21/fix-sharepoint-2013-workflow-recursion-prevention-part-2/]

List 2 successfully creates a new item, and I can get the GUID from that new item. This next step fails.

> HTTP Web Service info:
>   [%WorkflowContext:CurrentSiteURL%]_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List2')/items?$filter=GUID
>   eq '[%Variable: NewItemGUID%]'

Response Code = BadRequest. 
I also log the http web service call string:

> https://testwebsite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘List2’)/items?$filter=GUID
>   eq '38bc1c7d-e020-4c71-a8bf-5b1a344e6b1d'

What's wrong with the above?

Comment: encoding problem of your single quotes and missing a forward slash? `[site name]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items`

Comment: missing the slash '[site name]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘ListName’)/items'

Comment: Included more info on main question. Please consider and comment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have copied the URL from a site.  You have two issues with the URL:

```
[site name]_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘ListName’)/items
```

First, you need a `/` between `[site name]` and `_api`

Second, the quotes you are using are special characters, not real quotes.  `‘ListName’` is not the same as `'ListName'`.

So your full URL would be:

```
[site name]/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.
Quotes = I guess my pasting it into here changed the quotes. I’m using the correct ‘. 
[site name] missing /, I’m playing with HTTP web service and the variable for Current Site URL already has the / in it. Note - the query started to work ?!

Comment: Included more info on main question. Please consider and comment.

Answer (score 0):

Found a good resource that helped me out. http://codelesssharepointinfopath.com/tag/start-workflow/

Using the ‘call http web service’ I was able to get the guid of the workflow and the ID of the list item. Everything worked up to the last POST where the workflow is triggered.

```
[web site]_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/StartWorkflowOnListItemBySubscriptionId(subscriptionId='[guid of workflow]'),itemId='[id of list item]'
```

The http response code is OK, but nothing is happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: I needed to complete the Request Header in full: Accept / Content-Type / content-length / X-RequestDigest. 
Post still not working though.